# Run a certain code every x minute

Tags: c#, timer, stopwatch

I'm trying to make a program whereby it does something every x minutes. I have been experimenting with the Stopwatch function but it don't seem to run the code I want when the time is up.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch testing = new Stopwatch();
            testing.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(6001);
            TimeSpan ts = testing.Elapsed;
            int timer = Convert.ToInt32(String.Format("{0}", ts.Seconds));
            Console.Write(timer);

            while (testing.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(8))
            {

                timer = Convert.ToInt32(String.Format("{0}", ts.Seconds));
                if (timer % 60 == 0)
                {
                    //run x code every 1 minutes
                    Console.WriteLine("1 min" + timer);
                }


                timer = Convert.ToInt32(String.Format("{0}", ts.Seconds));
                if (timer % 120 == 0)
                {
                    //run x code every 2 minutes
                    Console.WriteLine("2 min" + timer);
                }
            }    

            testing.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by xxbbcc, here's an implementation using ManualResetEvent.WaitOne() with a TimeOut:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int TimeOut = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2).TotalMilliseconds;
        System.Threading.ManualResetEvent mreDuration = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);
        Task.Run(() => {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30).TotalMilliseconds);
            mreDuration.Set();
        });
        while(!mreDuration.WaitOne(TimeOut))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Two Minutes...");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Thirty Mintues!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Stopwatch` is a high-performance timer (usually with 100ns resolution) - it is entirely inappropriate for what you're trying to do. `Stopwatch` is used to measure time by taking snapshots of a system counter and then calculating the difference.

Since most of a scheduler's job is to wait until a job needs to be done, implementing a scheduler with a tight loop is extremely inefficient - the system is using CPU resources to decide to not do anything for most of the time.

To properly implement a scheduler (if that's what you're trying to do), look into using [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a timeout option.

Using an event puts your current thread to sleep (so it's not using system resources while it's doing nothing) and when the timeout expires, the event is triggered and the code can call the function that you're trying to schedule.

If you want nothing else than a simple timer that tells you when an interval elapsed, use [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead: this makes it much simpler to schedule a callback (the `Elapsed` event is called when the timer expires) and you don't have to run a loop during the wait.

**Edit:**

If you simply want to call a callback function periodically, a simple timer is easier to hook up than an event. Here's a code sample using `System.Timer` (not my code, I copy & pasted this from MSDN, linked above):

```
private static Timer m_oTimer;

public static void Main ()
{
    m_oTimer = new System.Timers.Timer ( 2 * 1000 * 60 ); // 2 minutes
    m_oTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent; // Timer callback
    m_oTimer.Enabled = true; // Start timer

    // Wait here (you can do other processing here, too)
    Console.WriteLine ( "Press the Enter key to exit the program... " );
    Console.ReadLine ();
    Console.WriteLine ( "Terminating the application..." );
}

private static void OnTimedEvent ( Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e )
{
    // This is called on a separate thread; do periodic processing here
    Console.WriteLine ( "The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime );
}
```

Comment: Hi xxbbcc, thanks for your reply. I have been trying out ManualResetEvent as per your suggestion as it seems to suit what I'm trying to do more, however I can only manage to make the code run once using the timer, what I'm looking for is every x minute, the code will run once.

For example, I set the program runtime to be 30 minutes. Within the 30 minutes run time, I want the program to Console.WriteLine("2 minutes is up") every 2 minutes repeatedly till the 30 minutes is over. Please help me out :)

Comment: @Konny I updated my answer with some code using `System.Timers.Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Timer`. If you want timer to stop running after, let's say, 'y' minutes, then you just store the start time in a variable and write the `Timer.Stop()` function so that it get executed after 'y' minutes (hint: write it in timer_tick event). Time period of the timer should be **HCF** of all **x**'s and **y**. Remember to set time period in miliseconds.