# Network discovery for multiple servers

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm making a WPF project where I need to find an idefinite number of devices on the network. To do this I need to send a UDP broadcast, catch the responses, and put them on a Collection.

My boss tells me that I should only send a broadcast every 5 minutes and I should avoid infinite while loops, which means that, by sending a broadcast, I need to collect every single response (limited by UDP nature, of course) and close the socket afterwards, and only open it again after 5 minutes.

I'm lost as to how I'm going to achieve this without a while(true) repeatedly waiting to read data. And even if I did that, it wouldn't avoid losing a response while processing another, forcing the program to wait another 5 minutes.

Comment: Have you asked your boss for an explanation for the reasoning? This also depends on how you launch your application.

Comment: @gunr2171 not really. When the application lauches it simply shows a list view with the devices found on the network. So the broadcast is sent right as the applicaton lauches, and then after 5 minutes, or if the user presses a refresh button.

Comment: By definition, any thing you're doing **every** X time units is an infinite loop. That's what 'every' means. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664448/run-a-certain-code-every-x-minute) might be helpful.